# How to type 'ज्ञ' in ubuntu 14.04 hindi keyboard

Tags: ubuntu, input, keyboard, hindi

I am having problems while typing 'ज्ञ' (gya) in hindi.

When I updated ubuntu from 13.10 to 14.04, I noticed that the old hindi keyboard was missing, instead in the text entry settings, I saw three new hindi input sources:

```
Hindi(Bolnagri)
Hindi(Wx)
Hindi(KaGaPa phonetic)
```

One day, when I was typing in LibreOffice Writer in hindi, I had to type 'ज्ञान', but, I couldn't find the letter 'ज्ञ'. I searched the Keyboard Layouts and Character Maps of all three input sources but couldn't find it... (This problem stays with text editors too!)

Please help me and tell me where it is on keyboard if you think you know the answer! ( it's been a week since I've been thinking "How can they make such a big mistake as forgetting 'ज्ञ' in hindi!!" )

(NOTE: The 'ज्ञान' above was pasted after searching 'gyan hindi' in google!! :D )

---

**EDIT:
The Solution is:**

```
 ज्ञ = ज + ् + ञ
```

There is no specific key for this!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It uses sanskrit rules like

```
 ज्ञ = ज + ् + ञ
```

The question is now solved!!!!

[See This Page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/251270/what-is-the-key-combination-for-alphabet-%E0%A4%9C%E0%A5%8D%E0%A4%9E-on-hindi-bolnagari-key-board)